# Python 3 str в timedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, datetime

я достаю из txt файла строку 0:16:00 и засовываю ее в переменную text_time и мне нужно ее засунуть в delta = timedelta(minutes=**text_time**), а он пишет что тип str нельзя засунуть в timedelta, как мне это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

text = "0:16:00"
time_parts = text.split(':')
time_elements = {
    'hours':    int(time_parts[0]),
    'minutes':  int(time_parts[1]),
    'seconds':  int(time_parts[2]),
}

time = datetime.timedelta(**time_elements)

print(time)
```

Comment: Спс, большое тебе